# Change URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've added a mobile version which redirects automatically with *MobileDetect.php*.

After redirect the URL is: `/index.html?mpage=home.`
For example, when the Desktop version URL is `/medical-studies`, the mobile is `/index.html?mpage=medical-studies`.

I want to use mod_rewrite or other mod if possible that the mobile version will show the same desktop URL;

I mean change

```
/index.html?mpage=X
```

to

```
/X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Blah...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?mpage=$1 [L]
```

If `User-Agent` matches some of mobile agents, mod_rewrite *internally* redirects the access to index.html with original path added. (URL shown in User-Agents does *not* changed.)

**Note**

- `RewriteCond` should be replaced with proper conditions.
- In server-side programs, you may have to refer `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` instead of `QUERY_STRING`.